# Создание Generic переменной

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть класс

```
public class BaseSearchRequest<TYPE extends SortType> {

    private List<TYPE> sort;
}
```

В другом классе я хочу использовать его

```
public class SearchRequest {

    @NotNull
    private BaseSearchRequest<ColumnType> sorting;
}
```

ColumnType - это наследник SortType.

Код компилируется, но при запросе появляется 500 ошибка: `"ColumnType" (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information"`

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: В том, что у `ColumnType` нет конструктора по умолчанию и не заданы другие способы десериализации.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а зачем ему конструктор? Без генрика работал без конструктора. Я так понял, что серализацию надо добавить. Я добавил в класс BaseSearchRequest следующее implements Serializable -
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -231945274016679375L; Не помогает(

Comment: Затем, что Spring пытается десериализовать какие-то данные в объект, чтобы присвоить этот объект полю sorting.